# Android WebView not able to play HTML5 videos

Tags: android, kotlin, html5-video, android-webview

I'm having trouble playing HTML5 videos in my Android WebView. I've tried enabling hardware acceleration and using a WebChromeClient, but the videos still won't play.

Here's the code I'm using to configure the WebView:-

```
val settings: WebSettings = binding.webView.settings
settings.setSupportZoom(true)
settings.builtInZoomControls = true
settings.displayZoomControls = false
settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
settings.layoutAlgorithm = WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.TEXT_AUTOSIZING
settings.domStorageEnabled = true
settings.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture = false
settings.allowFileAccess = true
settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK
settings.allowFileAccess = true
settings.allowContentAccess = true

// chromium, enable hardware acceleration
binding.webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)

// Additional settings
settings.setGeolocationEnabled(true) // enable geolocation
settings.databaseEnabled = true // enable database storage API
settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true) // enable support for multiple windows

binding.webView.scrollBarStyle = WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY
binding.webView.isScrollbarFadingEnabled = true
binding.webView.setDownloadListener(WebViewDownloadListener(this))
```

I'm also trying to play this video using the following URL: https://watchx.top/v/LIVtq4MIOiex/

Can anyone help me figure out why the video is not playing and suggest any potential solutions? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some HTML5 videos may not play in Android WebView due to format or codec issues.

Check the video format and codecs: Make sure the video you're trying to play is in a format and codec that is supported by Android WebView. You can check the list of [supported formats and codecs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats) in the Android documentation. If the video is not in a supported format, you may need to convert it to a compatible format.